# How do I see $\mu\left(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\mu \bigcap_{j=1}^n B_j\right)$.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\mu : \epsilon \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a measure from the $\sigma$-algebra $\epsilon$ into extended $\mathbb R$.

How do I see $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\mu \bigcap_{j=1}^n B_j\right) \quad ?$$

Is this true by definition or ...? The left-hand side is a well-defined set which $\mu$ is applied too, but the right-hand side is the limit of a sequence $\bigcap_{j=1}^n B_j$ might never equal $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not in general true.  For example, if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $B_n$ is the set $[n, \infty)$ then the LHS is $0$ but the RHS is $\infty$.

If the measure space is finite, however, then the result *is* true: one can simply take complements and use the corresponding result for unions, which follows from countable additivity.

Added in response to the comment:

If we have an increasing sequence of measurable sets $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq\ldots$ in an arbitrary measure space $E$, then the sets $A_1, A_2 \setminus A_1, A_3 \setminus (A_1 \cup A_2), \ldots$ (let's call them $C_1, C_2, C_3, \ldots$) are measurable, pairwise disjoint, and satisfy

$\bigcup C_n = \bigcup A_n$.

So we have

$\mu \left( \bigcup A_n \right) = \mu \left(\bigcup C_n \right) = \sum \mu ( C_n ) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \mu(C_j) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu ( A_n )$,

using countable additivity for the second and fourth equalities (we really only need finite additivity for the fourth).

If now we assume our measure space is finite, and we have a *decreasing* sequence of measurable sets $D_1, D_2, D_3, \ldots$, then their complements are an *increasing* sequence of measurable sets.  So we have

$\mu \left( \bigcap D_n \right) = \mu \left( E \setminus \bigcup \left( E \setminus D_n \right) \right) = \mu (E) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu \left( E \setminus D_n \right)$,

using the previous result and finiteness of $\mu(E)$.  And the RHS is just

$\mu (E) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \mu (E) - \mu ( D_n ) \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu ( D_n )$.

Hence

$\mu \left( \bigcap D_n \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu ( D_n )$.

For your example, simply set

$D_n = \bigcap_{j=1}^n B_j$.

Comment: Could you show your idea in the case the measure space is finite ? I don't see how I can prove the limit of the sequence equals the left-hand side.

Comment: @Jez I think the statement is true only if $B_n$ is a decreasing sequence of measurable sets, it is not sufficient to have a finite measure space.

Comment: Now is perfect! ;)

Comment: measure space is finite means $ A \in \epsilon \ (\mu(A) < \infty)$ ?

Comment: It means that the measure of the whole space (or, equivalently, the measure of every measurable set in the space) is finite.